# Sending a clear error message in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, sequelize.js

This is the **Sequelize request**:

```
models.client
 .create(clientInformation)
 .then(clientCreated => {
   logger.info("clientCreated", JSON.stringify(clientCreated));
    res.status(200).json(clientCreated);
   })
   .catch(error => {
    logger.error("error", JSON.stringify(error));
    res.status(400).json(error);
   });
```

This is the **client model**,

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var client = sequelize.define(
    "client",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
      },
      nomClient: DataTypes.STRING,
      numTel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        unique: true
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
      addresse: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
      ville: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

  return client;
};
```

I intentionally sent invalid data in the req.body in order to implement a clear error handling. So in the **response,** I get this:

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 177,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22003",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\numutils.c",
        "line": "253",
        "routine": "pg_strtoint32",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"clients\" (\"id\",\"nomClient\",\"numTel\",\"email\",\"addresse\",\"ville\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING *;",
        "parameters": [
            "Sam",
            "5578757867",
            "eazfafe@gmail.com",
            "Nabeul",
            "RueDuMerle",
            "2020-03-13 08:53:41.214 +00:00",
            "2020-03-13 08:53:41.214 +00:00"
        ]
    },
    "original": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 177,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22003",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\numutils.c",
        "line": "253",
        "routine": "pg_strtoint32",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"clients\" (\"id\",\"nomClient\",\"numTel\",\"email\",\"addresse\",\"ville\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING *;",
        "parameters": [
            "Sam",
            "5578757867",
            "eazfafe@gmail.com",
            "Nabeul",
            "RueDuMerle",
            "2020-03-13 08:53:41.214 +00:00",
            "2020-03-13 08:53:41.214 +00:00"
        ]
    },
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"clients\" (\"id\",\"nomClient\",\"numTel\",\"email\",\"addresse\",\"ville\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING *;",
    "parameters": [
        "Sam",
        "5578757867",
        "eazfafe@gmail.com",
        "Nabeul",
        "RueDuMerle",
        "2020-03-13 08:53:41.214 +00:00",
        "2020-03-13 08:53:41.214 +00:00"
    ]
}
```

In the **logged error** is this:

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: value "5578757867" is out of range for type integer
    at Query.formatError (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:366:16)
    at C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:72:18
    at tryCatcher (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\work\ViwoneSavServer\Backend\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
```

My problem is the information that exists in the logged message:

> value "5578757867" is out of range for type integer

is nowhere to be found in the **response body**!
So here are my questions:
**QUESION 1:** Why is the logged error different from the error in the response despite the fact that it's the same object?
**QUESION 2:** How do I only access the error message and send it in the response?
**NOTE:** The answers available in SO regarding sequelize error handling do not offer a response to this.
For example, most of the answers are like this:

```
sequelize.create({ 
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email })
.then((data)=> { res.send('mysuccess message'); })
.catch(Sequelize.UniqueConstraintError => {  
    res.send('myerrormessage');
}));
```

In other words, would I need to check for every error type?

Comment: I don't know if it can help you, but I tried to send error in a response using your err handler and it worked. I get a VERY different error object than yours though. Maybe it's sequelize version?

Comment: Or some other package?

Comment: @Eggon Maybe, I have Sequelize 5.21.2

Comment: I have Sequelize 5.21.3 and @types/sequelize 4.28.3.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked but I stumbled upon the same issue and resolved it by using `error.message` instead of `error` to get the exact error message from Sequelize. So your code would become

```
models.client
 .create(clientInformation)
 .then(clientCreated => {
   logger.info("clientCreated", JSON.stringify(clientCreated));
    res.status(200).json(clientCreated);
   })
   .catch(error => {
    logger.error("error", JSON.stringify(error.message));
    res.status(400).json(error.message);
   });
```